# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type x to interface type y

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, visual-c#-express-2010

I have some C# code written on machine #1 using Visual C# Express 2010. The code is dependent on some COM objects that are registered DLLs. It compiles and runs fine on machine #1. The COM objects are installed from a program called BostonWorkstation, which is installed on machines #1 and #2.

- Machine 1:

  - Code written on.
  - Visual C# 2010 Express installed.
  - The "BWS" DLLs are registered.
  - The program runs just fine.
  - Has .NET versions: v4.0, v4, v3.5, v3.0, v2.0
  - 32bit

- Machine 2:

  - The "BWS" DLLs are registered.
  - The program errors with `System.InvalidCastException` (below).
  - Visual C# 2010 Express not installed.
  - Has .NET versions: v4, v3.5, v3.0, v2.0, v1.1
  - 32bit

- Machine 3:

  - The "BWS" DLLs are not registered.
  - Visual C# 2010 Express installed.
  - The program errors (as expected) with: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (...): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (...)`
  - 32bit

When I try to run that program (compiled on machine 1) on machine #2 which also has the same exact registered DLLs, but the program fails to run. I also tried running it on machine #3, which doesn't even have the DLLs and that gets a different error as expected.

The runtime error on machine 2:

> 1 Unable to load BostonWorkstation, error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'BostonWorkStation70.BostonWorkStation'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{8C8144EF-ADB7-48FD-A5BB-6E55B8382B3E}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at TestBWS.LoginForm() in C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project1\TestBWS\CodeFile1.cs:line 67

(The Visual Studio folder reference is just the compile time path)

Checking the registry on machine 1 I found this:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{8C8144EF-ADB7-48FD-A5BB-6E55B8382B3E}

with a default REG_SZ value of `BostonWorkStation`

The code:

```
    using BostonWorkStation70; //line 1

    ...

    try
    {
        bwsLogin = new BostonWorkStation(); //line 67
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 Unable to load BostonWorkstation, error: " + e);
        System.Console.ReadLine(); //pause the debug window
        return false;
    }
```

I have tried running ProcMon to compare the machines Process logs, but there are thousands of entries for just this program and I'm not seeing any missing references offhand. I ran a compare, but a successful Process log has 5x as many lines.

From what I understand, running the program on machine 2 has it creating the BWS object as a generic `System.__ComObject` (instead of `BostonWorkStation70.BostonWorkStation`) and I don't know why. The DLLs etc are definitely correct on machine 2, otherwise I'd be getting that `Class not registered` error on runtime.

Why will the compiled program not run on machine 2? All the dependent COMs/DLLs are on it.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I think a possible explanation might be that the COM object relies on another (possibly non-COM) DLL, which isn't found on the machine where it doesn't work.

Comment: The proxy/stub DLL would be my guess.  Run SysInternals' ProcMon utility and compare the good vs the bad trace.

Comment: @HansPassant Good idea. I tried that, but the non-working spits out 1034 lines and the working spits out 6000+ lines (and that's not even fully running the program). This is a lot to compare.

Comment: Have you checked the 32/64-bit issue? A 32-bit registered COM Server is not visible to a 64-bit program, and a 64-bit registered COM Server is not visibile to a 32-bit program.Is it possible the servers and the programs run in different worlds?

Comment: The most apparent difference between machine #2 and the others is the lack of VSExpress on #2.  Is is possible you are missing some VSExpress redistributables?

Comment: @SimonMourier They're all 32bit.

Comment: @JBurace - are the OSes 32-bit as well?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I had updated my question as well.

Comment: @JBurace - have you checked the registry with procmon on the IID {8C8144EF-ADB7-48FD-A5BB-6E55B8382B3E}? Also, some COM programs need TLB (Type Library) files to be registered, not only DLL.

Comment: Have you install a previous version of the BostonWorkStation on the machine 2? Because, this problem appeared to me when I installed a previous version of the com object without changing the GUID. If the signature has changed, the object can't be load !

Answer (score 1):

if that error message is coming from machine #2, the one you said "Visual C# 2010 Express not installed."

why is it running from the default visual studio projects folder?

C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project1\TestBWS\CodeFile1.cs:line 67

You may have other problems....

Comment: That's just the compile-time path coming out of the PDB file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your COM object class from the library using regsvr32.exe on second machine?

To check that I'd search the registry on first and second machines looking for all possible `{8C8144EF-ADB7-48FD-A5BB-6E55B8382B3E}` string entries. If search results are different then it's probably the case.

Comment: You should avoid asking questions in your answer.  Instead, say "You Should."

Answer (score 0):

If the BostonWorkstation components are unmanaged - open them up in dependency walker to make sure that all their dependent dlls are present.

Odds are they are unmanaged components and make use of the MSVCRT 10. In which case you will need to install the [VS 2010 CRT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) on machine 2.

Comment: Does it matter that your link is C++? I did try installing that on machine 2, but still get the runtime error.

Comment: Yes - the vs 2010 crt only installs the msvcrt100 set of dlls into the windows sxs folders. If the BostonWorkstation components are managed - it wont help. If they are unmanaged - you should open them up in dependency walker and make sure that there are no missing dependencies.